# Can't Shut Down computer with windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: windows-8-preview

I downloaded Release Preview and installed it. I have a problem when I shut down the computer. After I press windows key + I > Power > Shut Down, a box pops up titled "Winlogon.exe - No Disk. Then under that is the message "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into Drive G". After hitting the retry button a couple of different times the screen finally goes dark. When I was going to turn it back on, I noticed the Power Button was still list. The only way to do a complete Shutdown is to hold in the power button directly.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sign in to the [Windows 8 Release Preview forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8?auth=1), and you post your specs and your issues, and you see if anyone there can assist you.

As has been pointed out, you installed a Beta version of Windows 8.  You are expected to be able to troubleshoot your own issues, as well as report them to Microsoft when possible to assist them in being able to resolve these issues for others.  Feel free to read the [Windows 8 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a pre-release of a Windows OS, so there will be bugs. I don't believe anyone can answer your question with any certainty.

Report the issue to the MS development team and pat yourself on the back; You found a bug.

If you want to check out a stable, and gorgeous (secure) OS, install Ubuntu or Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step the 'fix' is:

1. From the Metro "Start" page type "Shutdown Settings"
2. Click the "Settings" Icon on the right of the screen.
3. Click "Change what the power buttons do" on the left of the screen.
4. Click "Change settings that are not currently available"
5. Scroll to bottom of Dialog box.
6. Uncheck the box titled "Turn on fast startup (recommended)."
7. Click "Save Changes" button.
8. Exit Power Options Dialog box.